# Application design for container based trading development in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, algorithmic-trading

Excuse me if this is the wrong forum to be asking this question I did not see any other `stack` site that seemed to fit.

This application is a crypto trading application and it will have a few services one will be a polling service, to optimize this service I would like to implement an autoscaling Container that polls the crypto exchange. The issue I am struggling with is as I feed this application exchanges and symbols to poll every so often or receive a WebSocket connection, it will eventually hit its limit.

Ideally, I do not want to statically state what container polls what symbols, that should be automatic, so given an array of around 100 symbols what would be a good structure to follow when trying to spin up containers, which should be agnostic to the symbols, to minimize the number of containers to spin up.

We are planning on using AWS and are writing the application in node. I am not sure if we can get performance metrics from AWS on the fly, and based on the symbols being polled by one container spin up another one.

Say ContainerA has symbols a-c, Container 2 has symbols c-g, Container 3 has symbols g-h and so on...

What if the next day Container A gets overloaded, we would need to split the workload into a Container 10, which takes over b-c while ContainerA just works on symbols.

If anyone has any ideas about this I would appreciate some feedback.